# Order array of objects by date

Tags: javascript, html

for example

```
myArr= [
    {name:"Joe",  id:3,  date: "2012.10.12"},
    {name:"Ed",   id:43, date: "2012.02.12"},
    {name:"Mark", id:22, date: "2012.02.11"}
];
```

so how can I sort this Array by date?

This is just small example, but it will be like 1000 Objects inside that Array.
I have searched on the Internet and found some examples that used the `sort()` function but it doesn't work in my big Array.

Comment: So what is the code you used that is not working to sort it? Sorting large arrays can lead to slowness. We can not help you unless you show what you did that causes the slowness.

Comment: As hinted by epascarello, if you don't show what you have tried, we won't know where you went wrong, we can only solve the problem for you, which is not the intention of stack overflow. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: is not the same question !!! as

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the dates are just strings formatted as in your code, you can do this:

```
myArr.sort( (a,b) => a.date.localeCompare(b.date) )
```

The `sort` method takes as a parameter a function that will be called every time it needs to compare two elements of the array. So to sort by a particular field, you pass a function that compares those fields of the two objects passed in.

The sort comparator function has to return a special value indicating the correct order: -1 if the first parameter (conventionally called `a`) should come before the second (`b`); 1 if `b` should come before `a`; or 0 if they're equal (so the order doesn't matter). Fortunately, there's already a method that compares strings and returns the proper value for `sort` (if you call it on `a` and pass `b` as a parameter): `localeCompare`. Since the fields you're comparing are strings, you can just call that on the fields in your comparison function to return the proper value for the sort.

Comment: Omg you are my savior !! Thank you very much!!!